# I am unable to create SQLite Database. ERROR: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Here are following my classes:

**StatsObjectId.java**

```
public class StatsObjectId  extends Activity {
    DBClass db;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    db = new DBClass(this);
    }
    public void addObjId(String objid){
    Log.e("objectid","This is the object id going to store: "+objid);


            db.addObjectId(objid);  //This is the line# 105


            if(getObjId()){
        Log.e("objectid","Successfully stored!");
    }else{
        Log.e("objectid","Error in storing object id!");
        }
    }
    public boolean getObjId(){
    boolean result;
    try{
    c = db.getObjectId();
    c.moveToFirst();
    String str = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("objectid"));
    Log.e("objectid","Object id returned form DB: "+str);
    result = true;
    }catch(CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        Log.e("objectid","Cursor index out of bound");
        result = false;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("objectid","Some Another Exception");
        result = false;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

**ParseComServerAccessor.java**

```
public class ParseComServerAccessor {
//I am skipping some irrelevant code
     public void putStats(String authtoken, String userId, Tas statsToAdd) throws Exception {
     //Again skip some code
     //Here I got some HttpResponse and I need to extract an object id and save it to database
     HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
     String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
     JSONObject json = new JSONObject(responseString);
     Log.e("objectid","Now Object Id is: "+json.getString("objectId") );
     StatsObjectId ob = new StatsObjectId();


     ob.addObjId(json.getString("objectId")); // This is the line#156
     //skip some code
     }
}
```

**TasSyncAdapter.java**

```
public class TasSyncAdapter extends AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter {
    //skipped Constructor code
    public void onPerformSync(Account account, Bundle extras, String authority,
    ContentProviderClient provider, SyncResult syncResult) {
    //skipped some code
    ParseComServerAccessor parseComService = new ParseComServerAccessor();
    //skipped some code again


    parseComService.putStats(authToken, userObjectId, remoteTas); //This is the line# 134
    //skip some code
    }
}
```

Now finally when I run my app... this is the following Log Cat

```
Tag                    Text

objectid               This is the object id going to store: 9AFysqffz7
System.err             java.lang.NullPointerException
System.err             at com.myapp.ds_app.StatsObjectId.addObjId(StatsObjectId.java:105)
System.err             at com.myapp.ds_app.syncadapter.ParseComServerAccessor.putStats(ParseComServerAccessor.java:156)
System.err             at com.myapp.ds_app.syncadapter.TasSyncAdapter.onPerformSync(TasSyncAdapter.java:134)
System.err             at android.content.AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter$SyncThread.run(AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter.java:254)
```

**DBClass.java**

```
public class DBClass extends SQLiteOpenHelper { 
private static final String DATABASE_NAME="myapp.db";
public DBClass(Context cxt){
    super(cxt, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase mydatabase) {
    mydatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp (objectid STRING)");
}
public Cursor getObjectId(){
    Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT objectid FROM temp", null);
    return cursor;
}
public void addObjectId(String objid){
    try{
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues(1);

    Log.e("objectid","In DBClass and object id: "+objid);
    cv.put("objectid", objid);
    Log.e("objectid","Content value contains: "+cv.toString());
    getWritableDatabase().insert("temp", "objectid", cv);

    }catch(NullPointerException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Now, I am stucked at this point!
So far, I need to save just a single value. I tried to create a file instead of saving a value in database. But again there is some exception of ContextWrapper.

I am currently interested to deal with database.

Please let me know if you guys need any other information.

I would really appreciate if any one please explain this thing. I'm android newbie and would love to learn about this problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Lots of code. Please drill it down to what is relevant to your problem.

Comment: Just a shot, I would say `db` is `null` at line 105. Where is it initialized?

Comment: @Prateek Because, I want you guys to provide maximum things I can!

Comment: @dic19 what should I do then ? Where to initialized it?

Comment: @Yasir sometimes less is more. When you are finding a niddle in a haystack the smaller the haystack more easy is your task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
StatsObjectId ob = new StatsObjectId();
```

You are instanciating an Activity class. You are not allowed to do that. (There should really be something in Android to tell you when you do that) Basically, the context is not initialized, because android needs to do that in order to have a functional Activity.

Plus, Android (when it creates the Activity) calls the onCreate method with a proper context. You don't (and you can't, either), therefore your db is null.

In AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter, you have a `getContext` method to get a proper context. Use this to initialize your database and to insert data in it, rather than passing it to the Activity object.